# Returning “n” elements from array disturbed evenly generates stderr

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a solution which takes `m-element array` returns an `n-element array` distributed evenly. But for some value of **m** it generates `stderr`.

For example, if array will have 15 elements it `stderr` will be:

**PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -3**

**PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1**

```
class SpredArrayClass
{

var $array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

function spreadOutArray(array $array = [], $targetOutputLength = 10) {

    $array = $this->array;

    $originalArrayLength = count($array);

    if ($originalArrayLength == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($originalArrayLength <= $targetOutputLength) {
        return $array;
    }

    $output = [];
    $interval = round($originalArrayLength / $targetOutputLength);
    for ($index = $originalArrayLength - 1; count($output) < $targetOutputLength; $index -= $interval) {
        $output[] = $array[$index];
    }

    return array_reverse($output);
    }
}
```

Problem seem to be in this part:

```
$output = [];
$interval = round($originalArrayLength / $targetOutputLength);
for ($index = $originalArrayLength - 1; count($output) < $targetOutputLength; $index -= $interval) {
    $output[] = $array[$index];
}
```

`Undefinded offset stderr` appears at this line: `$output[] = $array[$index];`

**Demo** of code execution here: http://ideone.com/UrF9UK

Comment: Ever heard of  `range()`?

Comment: You could make your life a lot easier using php's range like @PHPglue rightly hinted....

Comment: Seems a new coding exam is coming up or similar. Similar questions using the same wordings have already been asked twice before today...

Comment: You cannot used a fixed value for each "step" ($interval), and at the same time guarantee the correct output length.

Comment: Explain what you mean by distributed evenly. An `array_splice()`?

Comment: Didn't you post a similar question earlier today?

Comment: @arkascha Are you sure it was posted by someone else? I think he just deleted and re-posted it.

Comment: I did, but I remove it. It was tagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You round too early. The steps ($interval) should be exact, because if the rounding is upward, the steps will bring you too fast to the start of the array and lead to negative indexes.

So only round when you *use* the resulting index:

```
$interval = $originalArrayLength / $targetOutputLength;
for ($index = $originalArrayLength - 1; count($output) < $targetOutputLength; $index -= $interval) {
    $output[] = $array[round($index)];
}
```

Comment: The solution you accepted will not always return an array with the desired number of elements, but less. If you run it on the sample array you provided in the question, the output array will only have 8 elements instead of 10. You really need to take out the `round` from the `$interval`: it is wrong arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, I got it. You are right. I had further issues with the code I selected as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Your Problem stems from the the condition in your `for` Loop. 
>   Change it to this:

```
        $output = [];
        $interval = round($originalArrayLength / $targetOutputLength);

        // JUST KEEP LOOPING & PUSHING TILL SO LONG AS $index IS GREATER THAN 0;
        for($index = $originalArrayLength - 1; $index>=0; $index -= $interval) {
            $output[] = $array[$index];
        }
```

Comment: It's better because it doesn't invoke round in every loop.